# Get "selected data" in a parallel coordinates chart using plotly to update table

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

As couple of users before, I want to update a table conditional on the selected lines in a parallel coordinates chart produced by plotly in R. I found a similar [question for Python](https://community.plotly.com/t/get-selected-data-in-a-parallel-coordinates-chart-to-update-table-resolved/24020) but don't get it working in R.

Though I get the latest dynamic interaction/selection by `event_data("plotly_restyle")`, I have the following issues:

- It provides only information for the axis the user has changed the latest and no information about all other axes which are returned as `NULL`. Though this is annoying, it can be resolved by updating e.g. a reactive value in the background observing the "event data" (not shown).
- Unselecting the selection area by a double click, gives back a `NULL` which has to be used for resetting the selection.
- In case the user modifies the order of the axis per manually dragging the axis, I get a different output and actually which lists a perfect summary of the order of all axes/variables and their user defined limits. This is actually the output I want to get in any case, so also when just a single axis is updated.

I give a minimal example to play with and to better understand my given points above (based on a official [plotly example](https://plotly.com/r/parallel-coordinates-plot/)). Any input welcome!

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")
library("DT")

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Example"),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text"),
    DTOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- reactive({read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bcdunbar/datasets/master/iris.csv")})
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  
    fig <- plot_ly(
      data = df(),
      source = "myplot",
      type = "parcoords",
      line = list(color = ~species_id,
      colorscale = list(c(0, "red"), c(0.5, "green"), c(1, "blue"))),
      dimensions = list(
        list(
          range = c(2,4.5),
          label = "Sepal Width", 
          values = ~sepal_width
        ),
        list(
          range = c(4,8),
          constraintrange = c(5,6),
          label = "Sepal Length", 
          values = ~sepal_length
        ),
        list(
          range = c(0,2.5),
          label = "Petal Width", 
          values = ~petal_width
        ),
        list(range = c(1,7),
        label = "Petal Length", 
        values = ~petal_length
        )
      )
    )
    
    fig
    
    fig <- event_register(fig, "plotly_restyle")
  })
  
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    event_data("plotly_restyle", source = "myplot", session = session)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      df()
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```